# Setting up VSCode with xdebug: pathMapping

Tags: xdebug, visual-studio-code

I am trying to set up debugging in VSCode and have run into a bit of a challenge. I typed the path to the localSourceRoot but Intellisense is telling me that it is deprecated and I should use pathMapping instead.

I am a newbie and don't know how to properly set that up. If someone could explain to me the variables and/or attributes pathMapping is requesting I would be forever in your debt.

My system info is as follows:
PHP version: 5.524
xdebug version: 2.2.5
OS Windows 8.1
Using Desktop Server version: 3.8.5

I checked the phpinfo() and it shows Xdebug in the file so I know that it is installed. The launch.json file is pretty basic with port 9000 and all of that. I just need to get that darned pathMapping thing done.

Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I guess you're using the PHP debug extension ?

https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-debug

The README.md says the following:

## Remote Host Debugging

To debug a running application on a remote host, you need to tell XDebug to connect to a different IP than localhost. This can either be done by setting xdebug.remote_host to your IP or by setting xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1 to make XDebug always connect back to the machine who did the web request. The latter is the only setting that supports multiple users debugging the same server and "just works" for web projects. Again, please see the XDebug documentation on the subject for more information.

To make VS Code map the files on the server to the right files on your local machine, you have to set the pathMappings settings in your launch.json. Example:

```
// server -> local
"pathMappings": {
  "/var/www/html": "${workspaceRoot}/www",
  "/app": "${workspaceRoot}/app"
}
```

Please also note that setting any of the CLI debugging options will not work with remote host debugging, because the script is always launched locally. If you want to debug a CLI script on a remote host, you need to launch it manually from the command line.

Comment: Thanks dethegeek. That is most helpful. :)

Comment: Hi, you're welcome ! If my answer solved your problem, you may mark my answer as approved solution !

Comment: Do I just click the check mark on the top left of your answer?

Comment: This was the las setting I was missing to make it work (the others being `xdebug.discover_client_host = 1` and firewall/ufw not authorizing port 9003).

Comment: @dethegeek: Trying to understand that last paragraph. Does this apply to PHPUnit tests? I'm trying to debug my phpunit tests in vscode, when my application (laravel) is running inside a docker container with xdebug and all this configuration, but it never hits any of my breakpoints.

Answer (score 5):

Thus is as much a reference to myself as well as others who might find this helpful. I am running VSCODE with xdebug and drupalvm and the following works for me after setting the following in php.ini

```
php_xdebug_idekey: VSCODE

{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

    {
        "name": "Listen for XDebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9000,
        "pathMappings": {
            "/var/www/drupalvm/drupal": "${workspaceRoot}/drupal",
          },
        "log": true
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch currently open script",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "port": 9000
    }
]
```

}