# Cannot debug php line by line in vscode

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

Given this setting in my vscode

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "hostname":"::1",
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html/": "${workspaceRoot}/item-street"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "hostname": "::1",
            "port": 9003
        }
    ]
}
```

and xdebug.ini

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.discover_client_host=1
```

This xdebug configuration is located in `/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/` in `WSL2` `Ubuntu-20.04`
following the setting here

https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-debug

But adding break point on php code and pressing `f5`, and visit the local php project in chrome
just nothing happen.

I did also read the following

[Setting up VSCode with xdebug: pathMapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49582866/setting-up-vscode-with-xdebug-pathmapping)

[VSCode - XDebug connected to client but break points does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64991324/vscode-xdebug-connected-to-client-but-break-points-does-not-work)

but seems doesn't work to my case.

Do you know why?

previously its fine but now it's not

Answer (score 0):

Just found an answer myself. On VSCode click the remote explorer not sure if this is really part of it and next install PHP debugger extension on Google Chrome.

Put a break point on PHP file, click PHP debugger on chrome, press f5 on VSCode, and it worked.

Edit:

My initial statement works, but not really the answer.
The actual answer is the https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-debug only support port:9000 or it's just xdebug the only support port 9000.

So instead of

```
xdebug.client_port=9003
```

Set it as

```
xdebug.client_port=9000
```